# When to use Multiplier in iOS AutoLayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, autolayout

An autolayout constraint can be definded as:

```
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, 
       attribute: .Bottom, 
       relatedBy: .Equal, 
       toItem: self.view, 
       attribute: .Bottom, 
       multiplier: 1, 
       constant: 0))
```

I did not understand what a use case would be for using the `multiplier`.

**When to use Multiplier in iOS AutoLayout?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26964139/understanding-multiplier-in-auto-layout-to-use-relative-positioning

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One use case that I commonly use is when I want one view to be 30% of the width of another view.  It would look like this:

```
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, 
   attribute: .Width, 
   relatedBy: .Equal, 
   toItem: self.view, 
   attribute: .Width, 
   multiplier: 0.3, 
   constant: 0))
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have two view. and your requirement is that one view is always half of other view or may be 10% of other view than you can use multiplier.

for ex,

[image]

i want this two view always in this proposition.

[image]

so drag and drop from one view to another and select equal height.

bt it shows errors that both view not in same height.

so select height[image]

now you have to change multiplier by calculating like (second_view_height/first_view_height). and add that in multiplier

[image]

this way you use in storyboard

for manual coding you can use this way

```
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, 
   attribute: .Width, 
   relatedBy: .Equal, 
   toItem: self.view, 
   attribute: .Width, 
   multiplier: 0.4869, 
   constant: 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Apple documentation :

> Auto Layout calculates the first item’s attribute to be the product of the second item’s attribute and this multiplier. Any value other than 1 creates a proportional constraint.

Take a look at this link : [Auto Layout Multiplier](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_auto_layout/chapters/EditingConstraintAttributesintheAttributesInspector.html)