# Restricting range of constraint for dynamic UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, storyboard, scrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` with couple `UILabel`s where I don't know the content of before execution. All the contents are embedded in a `UIView` (for the scrolling to work).

I also have a `UIImageView` that sits on top. So the layout if roughly like this

```
-------------------
|                 |
|   UIImageView   |
|                 |
|     UILabel     |
|                 |
|     UILabel     |
|                 |
|     UILabel     |
|                 |
|     UILabel     |
|                 |
-------------------
```

All `UIView`s are horizontally centered and have a leading and trailing space of 20. Each `UILabel` has a top and bottom space of 20.

And now comes the current problem. I want to have a varying top space for the `UIImageView` depending on what the screen size. If I have a fixed top space of lets say 20, then everything works. But if I try to set a range, lets say `lessOrEqualTo` 50 and `greaterOrEqualTo` 10, then I get a constraint error saying that the scroll view needs constraints for y position or height.

So how can I set the range of the top space without getting constraint error?

**EDIT**: These are my current constraints:
[image: Constraints]

Comment: Can you add what constraints you have given to the scrollview, uiimageview and all uilabels?

Comment: @agent_stack Updated with an image of my constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. 
1) You can have fixed image height and adjustable top space
2) You can have adjustable image height and fixed top space

Otherwise, How can the os determine those factors? Just think.

Comment: Forgot to mention, but yes, my image height is fixed. Will update my question

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `UIScrollView` height is calculated by its contents. For example here,

```
scrollview.height = imageView.top + imageView.height + label1.top + label1.height + label2.top + label2.height + label2.bottom
```

This all things must be constant at the run time you can change their values but it cant be dynamic like constraints you have give **lessOrEqualTo 50 and greaterOrEqualTo 10**. Because in this case it is unable to predicate the `scrollview.height` as it described above.

> **Suggestions**

1. Take the `outlet` of top constraint of `imageView.top` and change its `constant` value.
2. Give the multiplier to the `imageView.top`. It will automatically arranged according to your screen height.

If you need any further help or details you can ask.

Hope my answer helps you.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your second suggestion?

Comment: @JasonMcKenzy best explanation is given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26964139/understanding-multiplier-in-auto-layout-to-use-relative-positioning)